# How to save and retrieve foregin language(Malayalam ) datas in sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to  save Malayalam language datas in sql server 2008.I have installed Malayalam font in system and in my  application i changed TextBox font into Malayalam. So it displayed in malayalam  but actually its  English letters.If am saving into database it stored in English,But i want to save TextBox value in Malayalam to database .

Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nvarchar datatype in the tables which will store unicode data.

Make sure that your database calls also use nvarchar.

Answer (score 1):

I just followed my own style of coding. so please consider this when you follow me.

First I created the MySql database.

after creating database, in mysql command prompt, give the command:

SET NAMES = UTF8;

table and columns to store unicode are to be set with collation property as utf8-utf_general_ci. Each and every column which meant to store unicode, is to be selected and set collation property to utf8-utf_general_ci.

Now in C#.

my connection string is set as usual but with addition of a single attribute like this:

constring = @"SERVER=localhost;" + @"PORT=3306;" + @"DATABASE=gayakidb;" + @"UID=root;" + @"PASSWORD=mysql;" + @"charset=utf8;";

Next, installed unicode font in the 'Display language setting' of your system OS. Or, you can copy and paste the font file (true type file) in the Fonts folder of Operating System.

Then I set the font property of the textbox object or any other tool object in property page.

More over, if you need to type in unicode font using your keyboard, you need to install the unicode language for keyboard layout. That could be done using the option for regional language settings of your Operating System.

Done. with these settings, i coded module for saving data and while running the ocde, it successfully done the work.